# Convert first line of file into array C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a file called file.txt

```
1 2 3
ugjfnuwd
gjufjfg
```

and I want to extract the first line of this file "1 2 3" and turn it into an array in c++ so the end result would look something like this

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I've been experimenting and researching for around 2 hours with little progress. Please help

Comment: "Please help" [is not a valid question for Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), sorry.

Comment: `std::ifstream f("yourfile.txt"); int arr[3]; for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { std::cin >> arr[i]; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read the line into an `std::string`, then use an `std::istringstream` to parse the integers out of the line, something on this general order:

```cpp
// open the input file:
std::istream infile("file.txt");

// read in the line
std::string line;
std::getline(infile, line);

// put the line into a stringstream
std::istringstream parser(line);

// initialize the vector from the numbers in the stringstream:
std::vector<int> numbers{ std::istream_iterator<int>(parser), {} };

// print out the result, one number per line:
for (int i : numbers)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line into a string like normal and then split the string into an array with the delimiter being the space character.

Comment: please consider adding examples, or syntax of code along with the hints/explanations.